# Which open-source monitoring product uses a PostgreSQL backend, can be automated, run on CentOS7 and use Nagios plugins?

Tags: open-source, automation, monitoring, postgresql

**Aim**

The aim is to replace Opsview that is used to monitor all systems and related processes in the company as it does not meet now-a-days requirements:

1. PostgreSQL backend
2. Open-source
3. Automated deployment (e.g. Puppet)
4. CentOS7
5. Nagios plugins

---

**Attempts**

Googling: *monitoring open source linux systems* results in:

1. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
2. [Top 5 best system monitoring tools](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/top-5-best-network-monitoring-tools/): nagios, cacti, top, zabbix, munin
3. [Icinga](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart-icinga.html)
4. [zenoss core](http://www.zenoss.com/)
5. [Opsview core](http://www.opsview.com/products/opsview-core)

---

**Expected result**

The expectation was that Googling would indicate whether one of the software packages meets the demands as defined in the aim paragraph.

---

**Current outcome**

Opsview core will not be an option as it seems to be restricted to a MySQL backed. Nagios is not an option as well as this is used by Opsview and seems to be restricted to MySQL as well.

Although Zabbix can run on a PostgreSQL backend it seems not to be fully automated.

Comment: Much as I like PostgreSQL ... why? A RDBMS isn't really the ideal storage for RRD-like data.

Comment: @CraigRinger The company want to standardize everything. It would like to phase out MySQL and replace it by PostgreSQL. Perhaps we should decide to not use a database anymore. We are only using the monitoring to check the current status.

Comment: @CraigRinger RRD? [Round Robin Database](http://www.loriotpro.com/Products/On-line_Documentation_V5/LoriotProDoc_EN/V22-RRD_Collector_RRD_Manager/V22-A1_Introduction_RRD_EN.htm)? I have never heard of it before. I will read about it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/).

It understands Nagios plugins, can use Postgres, and can be instrumented with Puppet or Chef.